# The Layout Constraint Helper Flow class cannot be found in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, spacing

I am attempting to chain together three widgets using java syntax, not XML. Android Studio complains that the constraintLayout helper is an unknown symbol.

This is the statement where I am attempting to  applying a Chain Style of "spread"

```
centerSet.setVerticalChainStyle( viewid: Flow.CHAIN_SPREAD);
```

Android studio complains that it cannot resolve the 'Flow' class.  I included the following import statement:

```
import android.support.constraint.helper;
```

The Android documentation list this as the location of the Flow class. Androd studio flags this import statement stating that helper' is an unknown symbol.